# xmpppy how to send iq object?

Tags: python, pyqt, xmpp, xmpppy

I have an internal server xmpp (openFire) and I develop an intern chat client.

I'm using xmpppy and pyqt for that but I have some problem with the server/client talk.

I would like for try, have an handler to get the version of the chat.

the handler :

```
self._client.registerHandler("iq", self.handleVersion, typ = "get", ns = xmpp.NS_VERSION)

def handleVersion(self):
    print "do stuff"
```

this handler works if I'm using another chat client and ask for the version. (ie, Spark 2.6.3)

the iq object send by Spark for ask the version is :

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="myUserName@myServer/519c3e1e" type="get" id="reLOy-26" from="contactName@myServer/Spark 2.6.3"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:version" /></iq>
```

but, if I try to do the same iq object with my chat client, it doesn't work (he desn't enter in  def handleVersion(self):

when I create my own request :

```
reply = xmpp.protocol.Iq(to="uga@chob04", typ="get", frm="phid@chob04", xmlns ="jabber:client") #, 
reply.setQueryNS(xmpp.NS_VERSION)
self._client.send(reply)
```

my Iq object before send is :

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="myUserName@myServer" from="contactName@myServer" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:version" /></iq>
```

and after send is :

```
<iq to="myUserName@myServer" from="contactName@myServer" id="9" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:version" /></iq>
```

I don't know why this request doesn't work.